# How do I make a subdomain of a subdomain?

Tags: apache2, dns

I have a server that hosts mydomain.com.  Then I have a server that hosts subdomain1.mydomain.com.

On the subdomain1.mydomain.com server, how do I make subdomains?  For instance I want to create subdomain2.subdomain1.mydomain.com

I have my subdomain1.mydomain.com site in /home/USER/public_html and it is working just fine.  But When I try to create subdomain2.subdomain1.mydomain.com, it says Server not found in the browser.  I have tried so many configurations in my /etc/hosts and /etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain2.subdomain1.mydomain.com, without any luck

Can I get some detailed instructions maybe?  I have looked everywhere and every place tells you different, with no luck.

Ubuntu Server 11.10 w/ the Lamp Stack option

Comment: What software/service provides the answers for subdomain1.mydomain.com?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  Could you explain that more?

Comment: Hard to know, can you pastebin your /etc/hosts as well as your configuration files.

Comment: /etc/hosts: http://pastebin.com/kAd2tvtc

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain.domain.com: http://pastebin.com/a9j4gXXQ

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-available/test1.subdomain.domain: http://pastebin.com/8RCiiNpF

Comment: @joe I did not gather that you were using /etc/hosts for name resolution and hoped to learn which name server was in use.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @joe The /etc/hosts file was the method used for host name resolution before DNS was invented. And I assumed you were using a DNS server.

Comment: Should I set up a DNS Server?

Comment: @joe No need to install and learn DNS if this suites you; on the other hand, DNS is designed for resolving host names and addresses...

Answer (score 1):

You should put your subdomain2 DocumentRoot in your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`
like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
    ServerName subdomain2.subdomain.1.com
    DocumentRoot /home/USER/public_html
    <Directory /home/USER/public_html/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You shouldn't put it in the default, that's really not a best practice for multiple virtual hosting